# Asynchronous hardware communication - Library Design

Tags: c#, multithreading, api

I've got some equipment ("tool") that communicates over CANbus that I need to communicate with.  I'm using a USB->CAN dongle that provides a basic .Net control library.  I'm in the process of writing a library that abstracts out tool communication, and I'd like some comments on the design.

Note that I've mostly been living in a .NET 2.0 world for a very, very long time.  I've done some crash course style study of some of the new threading concepts in .NET 4.5, but I'm sure my code is a mix of old and new style.

Here is a brief overview of the architecture:

- The CAN library (`PCANbasic`) allows one to scan for a usb dongle and open a connection. One can write CAN packets to the connection, or poll for received packets.
- The tool has a custom communication scheme where a command or response can consist of one or more CAN packets.
- The goal of my library is to hide the PCAN library.  I want to be able to open a connection (`CanbusConnection`) and be able to send commands and receive command responses (each command is an instance of an abstract class, `CommandBase`).
- All the communication has to happen on a background thread so it doesn't stall the UI.

#### CanbusConnection.cs

This class just wraps the underlying PCAN library to establish a connection, then it starts a background thread that polls for incoming CAN messages every ~100ms.  It exposes a `CanbusPacketReceived` event.  Closing the CanbusConnection class stops the background thread, then closes the underlying PCAN connection.

```
public delegate void CanbusPacketReceivedEventHandler(object sender, TPCANMsg packet);
public class CanbusConnection : IDisposable
{
    #region Declarations
    TPCANHandle _handle;
    Thread _canbusListenerThread;
    #endregion

    #region Properties
    public bool IsOpen { get; private set; }
    public event CanbusPacketReceivedEventHandler CanbusPacketReceived;
    #endregion

    public CanbusConnection()
    {
        _handle = 0;
        IsOpen = false;
    }

    public bool Open()
    {
        if (IsOpen) { return true; }

        try
        {
            IsOpen = TryInitializePCANChannel(out _handle);
            if(IsOpen)
            {
                _canbusListenerThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(CanbusListener));
                _canbusListenerThread.Start();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error("Error opening PCAN connection: {Message}, Error: {Error}", ex.Message, ex);
            throw ex;
        }
        return success;

    }

    private void CanbusListener()
    {
        TPCANMsg msg;

        while (IsOpen)
        {
            try
            {
                while(PCANBasic.Read(_handle, out msg) == TPCANStatus.PCAN_ERROR_OK)
                { 
                    string hexData = string.Join(" ", msg.DATA.Select(b => b.ToString("X2")));
                    Log.Information("EventType: {EventType}, Data: {Data}", CanbusConnectionEventType.CAN_RX, hexData);
                    NotifyCanbusPacketReceived(msg);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Warning("EventType: {EventType}, Message: {Message}", CanbusConnectionEventType.CAN_RX, ex.Message);
            }
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    }

    private void NotifyCanbusPacketReceived(TPCANMsg msg)
    {
        if (CanbusPacketReceived != null)
        {
            CanbusPacketReceived(this, msg);
        }
    }

    public void WriteCanMsg(TPCANMsg msg)
    {
        try
        {
            PCANBasic.Write(_handle, ref msg);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error("Error writing CAN message: {Error}, Bytes: {Bytes}", ex.Message, String.Join(" ", msg.DATA));
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    private bool TryInitializePCANChannel(out TPCANHandle handle)
    {
        // SNIP
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Close CAN connection
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="handle">an open CAN connection</param>
    private void UninitializPCANChannel(TPCANHandle handle)
    {
        IsOpen = false;
        if(_canbusListenerThread.IsAlive && !_canbusListenerThread.Join(200))
        {
            _canbusListenerThread.Abort();
        }
        TPCANStatus status = PCANBasic.Uninitialize(handle);
        Log.Information("Uninitializing channel {Channel}: {Status}", handle, status);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if(IsOpen)
        {
            UninitializPCANChannel(_handle);
        }
    }

    public void Close()
    {
        this.Dispose();
    }
}
```

#### CommandBase.cs

All commands extend the abstract`CommandBase`.  CommandBase has logic to monitor incoming CAN packets and parse them for a response for the given command. 
A given command has:

- Command specific properties
- Logic to encode the properties to a CAN message
- Logic to decode a byte array back into properties/basic types
- CommandBase defines several abstract methods that a command must implement so that CommandBase can parse the incoming CAN messages and identify the response for the given command (The first several bytes in a CAN message are used to identify the command/response)

When sending a command:

- The command encodes itself as a CAN message and passes it to the `ExecuteCommandBase(..)` method in CommandBase (This is called from the UI thread).
- CommandBase sends the packets, and subscribes to the 
  `CanbusConnection.CanbusPacketReceived` event.
- The CanbusPacketReceived event handler is called from the background thread.  I have a simple state machine that looks for for a matching set of first bytes for each incoming message.  After that it collects packets and appends the payload to a list until the expected number of packets have been received.
- I use an AutoResetEvent with a timeout to synchronize between the background thread parsing and the UI thread.
- I use an extension method to convert the `AutoResetEvent.WaitOne()` to a `Task<>`

---

```
public abstract class CommandBase
{
    #region Parse Engine Data Structures
    private enum ParseState
    {
        NoCommand,
        CommandInProgress,
        CommandTimeout
    }

    private class ParseData
    {
        public List<byte> RxBytes { get; set; }
        public int NumPacketsReceived { get; set; }

        public int NumPacketsExpected { get; set; }

        public ParseData()
        {
            RxBytes = new List<byte>();
            NumPacketsReceived = 0;
            NumPacketsExpected = 1;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    private ParseState _parseState;
    private ParseData _parseData;
    private AutoResetEvent _parseWaitHandle;

    #region Properties

    /// <summary>
    /// Time in milliseconds before a timeout occurs
    /// </summary>
    public int ResponseTimeoutMilliseconds { get; protected set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// True is a timeout occurred
    /// </summary>
    public bool TimoutOccured { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the reply length
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="firstPacketData">The first packet's data, for use with variable length responses</param>
    /// <returns>Number of packets required for the whole command</returns>
    protected abstract int GetReplyPacketLength(byte[] firstPacketData);
    #endregion


    #region Constructor
    protected CommandBase()
    {
        TimoutOccured = false;
        ResponseTimeoutMilliseconds = 500; // default timeout 500ms
    }
    #endregion


    protected async Task<bool> ExecuteCommandBase(CanbusConnection connection, TPCANMsg msg)
    {
        if(connection == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("connection");
        }
        if(!connection.IsOpen)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Connection is not open");
        }

        _parseState = ParseState.NoCommand;
        _parseData = new ParseData();

        using (_parseWaitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(initialState: false))
        {

            lock (connection)
            {
                connection.CanbusPacketReceived += Connection_CanbusPacketReceived;
                connection.WriteCanMsg(msg);
            }

            bool allPacketsReceived = await _parseWaitHandle.WaitOneAsync(ResponseTimeoutMilliseconds);

            lock (connection)
            {
                connection.CanbusPacketReceived -= Connection_CanbusPacketReceived;
            }

            if (allPacketsReceived)
            {
                if(Parse(_parseData.RxBytes.ToArray()))
                {
                    Log.Information("Received {MsgType} message", this.GetType().ToString());
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    Log.Information("Received malformed {MsgType} message", this.GetType().ToString());
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // timeout
                Log.Warning("{MsgType} message Timeout", this.GetType().ToString());
                TimoutOccured = true;
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Parses the incoming canbus packets, looking for a matching response start seqeunce.  Returns true if the start sequence is found
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="firstPacketBytes">canbus packet data bytes</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected abstract bool IsMatch(byte[] firstPacketBytes);

    /// <summary>
    /// Parses a byte sequence into the command response
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="data">an array of bytes, guaranteed to be enough for the expcted response length</param>
    /// <returns>true if parse was successful, false if errors were encountered</returns>
    protected abstract bool Parse(byte[] data);

    // This function runs on (is called from) the CanbusConnection.CanusListenerThread, a background thread
    // The _parseWaitHandler is initialized on either the UI thread or a Task generated on the UI thread (I'm not quite clear on the underlying details)
    //   so this signals the waiting thread.  That thread is also configured with a timeout, so if parsing never completes, the calling thread
    //   should still be notified
    private void Connection_CanbusPacketReceived(object sender, TPCANMsg packet)
    {
        switch (_parseState)
        {
            case ParseState.NoCommand:
                if (IsMatch(packet.DATA))
                {
                    _parseData.NumPacketsExpected = GetReplyPacketLength(packet.DATA);
                    if (_parseData.NumPacketsExpected == 1)
                    {
                        _parseWaitHandle.Set();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _parseState = ParseState.CommandInProgress;
                        _parseData.RxBytes.AddRange(packet.DATA);
                        _parseData.NumPacketsReceived++;
                    }
                }
                break;

            case ParseState.CommandInProgress:
                _parseData.RxBytes.AddRange(packet.DATA);
                _parseData.NumPacketsReceived++;

                if (_parseData.NumPacketsReceived == _parseData.NumPacketsExpected)
                {
                    _parseWaitHandle.Set();
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

#### Example Command - CmdGetRpm.cs

Here is an example command that gets the firmware version of one of the boards.

```
public class CmdMpuSerialNumber : CommandBase
{
    public string SerialNumber { get; protected set; }

    public async Task<bool> ExecuteCommand(CanbusConnection conn)
    {
        this.ResponseTimeoutMilliseconds = 100000;
        TPCANMsg msg = new TPCANMsg();
        msg.DATA = new byte[] { 0xAA, 0xAA, 0x08, 0x08, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        msg.LEN = 8;
        msg.MSGTYPE = TPCANMessageType.PCAN_MESSAGE_EXTENDED;
        msg.ID = (uint)CanbusAddress.PC;

        return await this.ExecuteCommandBase(conn, msg);
    }

    #region CommandBase members
    static readonly byte[] RX_PATTERN = new byte[] { 0xAA, 0xAA, 0x08 };

    protected override int GetReplyPacketLength(byte[] firstPacketData)
    {
        return 5;
    }

    protected override bool IsMatch(byte[] firstPacketBytes)
    {
        int numItems = Math.Min(RX_PATTERN.Length, firstPacketBytes.Length);
        return firstPacketBytes.Take(numItems).SequenceEqual(RX_PATTERN.Take(numItems));
    }

    protected override bool Parse(byte[] data)
    {
        IEnumerable<byte> query = data.Skip(8).TakeWhile((currentByte) => currentByte != 0);
        byte[] substringBytes = query.ToArray<byte>();
        SerialNumber = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(substringBytes);
        //SerialNumber = BitConverter.ToString(data, 8);  // the serial number starts at the begining of the second packet, byte 8
        return true;
    }
    #endregion
}
```

#### Example UI Code - Form1.cs

And here is an example of using the code in the GUI

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    CanbusConnection _conn;
    //CommandParser _parser;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            _conn = new CanbusConnection();
            _conn.Open();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ConnectionError: " + ex.ToString());
        }
    }


    private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(_conn != null)
        {
            _conn.Close();
            _conn = null;
        }
    }

    private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CmdMpuSerialNumber cmd = new CmdMpuSerialNumber();
        bool result = await cmd.ExecuteCommand(_conn);
        MessageBox.Show(cmd.SerialNumber, "MPU SN");
    }
}
```

#### Final Thoughts

- I know the `Thread.Sleep()` has a bit of code smell, but I couldn't think of another way to do it.  I briefly considered timers an a bunch of other stuff, but Thread.Sleep gets the same result without needing to instantiate a bunch of other objects.
- This was a big reference for me in designing this: [Creating Async Libraries That Are Modular, Reusable and Fast, in Microsoft Visual C# and Visual Basic](https://channel9.msdn.com/events/TechEd/2013/DEV-B318?term=async%20and%20await&lang-en=true&pageSize=15&skip=30)
- Comments on naming/syntax/style are appreciated, but comments on the design are appreciated more :)

Comment: Do you happen to have a link to some document with a specification you used to implement it?

Comment: @t3chb0t I'm not sure what you are asking for, which "it"?   This library is for a new project. I want to be able to support any arbitrary communication with the tool.  I'll be writing a Winforms project to use the library.  The first goal for it is reading and writing configuration information to/from the tool. The tool CAN communication spec is proprietary and cannot be shared.

Comment: It's hard to review this communication protocol without some kind of specification. We don't know packet sizes, recovery, latency, command specs.

Comment: oh, ok, I thought it's something common and was thinking about a specification that would explain all that magic numbers, and how the communication works in detail. If it's proprietary... do you think it's a good idea to post it here? Or have you obfuscated it?

Comment: CANbus messages have an 8 byte payload.  It has support for error recovery, message priority, sophisticated addressing, etc.  The original designers of this system used none of it.  It's basically a glorified FIFO, more or less equivalent to a serial port.  So timings, etc. don't matter for this.  Data is dumped on the bus in 8 byte chunks, and while it's not guaranteed to be half duplex, it de facto is half duplex.   This simplifies a lot of stuff.

Comment: It's one command, to get the version of a board, and I changed the magic numbers.  I think we're good.  But I won't be posting the whole spec.  :)

Comment: Also, to clarify,  I have no control over the command spec.  I'm asking for a review of the multi-threading design of this (background poll thread, foreground/background synchronization, use of Tasks (which are new for me)), and use of best practices

Comment: The problem is that the multi-threaded aspect correlates with the API spec. For instance, are concurrent requests over the bus allowed? This has a huge design impact in my opinion. I will review some basic .NET do's/don't, not the multi-threaded nature because you are not allowed to provide a spec.

Comment: Assume that the bus is half duplex and that only one command will be executed at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Testability

This is my main concern when creating an API that talks to external references, in this case *The CAN library*. 
The problem with this library is that we are forced to consume a static class `PCANbasic`. 
There is no interface provided for us to work with. Testing our own code depends on a connection to the CAN bus.

> ```
> // static class is a tight dependency, hard to mock out
> PCANBasic.Write(_handle, ref msg);
> ```

Therefore, it is up to us to create an interface, an implementation using the static library and use a variable of this interface `_canBusService` in `CanbusConnection`. This way, we can

- mock the library for unit tests
- use a different version of the library (considering the signatures remain)

interface `ICanService`

```
public interface ICanService : IDisposable
{ 
    TPCANHandle Handle { get; }
    bool Initialize();
    TPCANStatus Read(out TPCANMsg message);
    void Write(ref TPCANMsg message);
}
```

implementation `CanService`

```
public class CanService : ICanService
{
    public TPCANHandle Handle { get; private set; }

    public bool Initialize()
    {
        // Handle = [redacted]
        return true;
    }

    public TPCANStatus Read(out TPCANMsg message)
    {
        return PCANBasic.Read(Handle, out message);
    }

    public void Read(ref TPCANMsg message)
    {
        PCANBasic.Write(Handle, ref message);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        PCANBasic.Uninitialize(Handle);
        Handle = 0;
    }
}
```

---

## Data Integrity

You have stated in the comments that the library is half-duplex, non-concurrent. This simplifies design, but still requires measures to enforce thread-safety.

Consider using a lock for `Open` and `WriteCanMsg` to avoid race conditions.

```
public object SyncRoot { get; } // .. create a new object() in the constructor
```

method `Open`

Since no lock is used, another thread can call the method after we think it is not opened.

> ```
> if (IsOpen) { return true; }
> // .. other code that assumes IsOpen == false
> ```

We no longer store the handle and use the newly created interface.

> `IsOpen = TryInitializePCANChannel(out _handle);`

```
IsOpen = _canBusService.Initialize();
```

What happens if the call was not succesfull?

> ```
> if(IsOpen)
> {
>     _canbusListenerThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(CanbusListener));
>     _canbusListenerThread.Start();
> } // else ??
> ```

Invert the condition and trow on failure.

```
if (!IsOpen)
{
    throw new IOException("Failure initializing CAN bus");
}
```

Use `throw` to keep the original stacktrace.

> ```
> catch(Exception ex)
> {
>     Log.Error("Error opening PCAN connection: {Message}, Error: {Error}", ex.Message, ex);
>     throw ex;
> }
> ```

```
catch(Exception ex)
{
    Log.Error("Error opening PCAN connection: {Message}, Error: {Error}", ex.Message, ex);
    throw;   // preserves stacktrace
}
```

refactor `Open`

```
public bool Open()
{
    lock (SyncRoot)
    {
        if (IsOpen) { return true; }

        try
        {
            IsOpen = _canBusService.Initialize();
            if (!IsOpen)
            {
                throw new IOException("Failure initializing CAN bus");
            }
            _canbusListenerThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(CanbusListener));
            _canbusListenerThread.Start();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error("Error opening PCAN connection: {Message}, Error: {Error}", ex.Message, ex);
            throw;
        }
        return success;
    }
}
```

method `WriteCanMsg`

Guard against bad user input.

```
msg = msg ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(msg));
```

Same tips as with `Open`: use lock, interface, throw

refactor `WriteCanMsg`

```
public void WriteCanMsg(TPCANMsg msg)
{
    msg = msg ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(msg));
    lock (SyncRoot)
    {
        try
        {
            _canBusService.Write(ref msg);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error("Error writing CAN message: {Error}, Bytes: {Bytes}", ex.Message, String.Join(" ", msg.DATA));
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

The commands should reuse the lock. For instance, `CommandBase`

```
 //lock (connection)
 lock (connection.SyncRoot)
 {
     connection.CanbusPacketReceived += Connection_CanbusPacketReceived;
     connection.WriteCanMsg(msg);
 }
```

refactor `CanbusListener` to use `_canBusService`

```
// ..
while(_canBusService.Read(out msg) == TPCANStatus.PCAN_ERROR_OK)
{
    // ..
}
// ..
Thread.Sleep(100); // <- I am surprised this is required. 
                   //    I would expect `_canBusService.Read` to be blocking.
```

---

## Resource Management

Let `Close` do the actual work.

```
public void Close()
{  
    lock (SyncRoot) 
    {
        if (IsOpen)
        {
           _canBusService.Dispose();
           if(_canbusListenerThread.IsAlive && !_canbusListenerThread.Join(200))
           {
               _canbusListenerThread.Abort();
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Have `Dispose` calling `Close`. You could also refactor `Dispose` to use the dispose pattern. Clear event listeners and provide a destructor.

```
public void Dispose()
{
    Dispose(true);
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
}

~CanbusConnection()
{
    Dispose(false);
}

protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing)
    {
        CanbusPacketReceived = null;
    }
    Close();
}
```

---

## Separation of Concerns

- I would not expect `CommandBase` to have an operation 
  `protected async Task<bool> ExecuteCommandBase(CanbusConnection connection, TPCANMsg msg)`. 
  This should be a method on `CanbusConnection` as 
  `public async Task<bool> ExecuteCommand(CommandBase command)`.
- Each specific command should provide a method `BuildMessage()` which would create the `TPCANMsg` from own state.

code `CanbusConnection.ExecuteCommand`

```
public class CanbusConnection
{
    // ..

    public async Task<bool> ExecuteCommand(CommandBase command)
    {
        var message = command.BuildMessage();
        // continue implementation with 'message' ..
    }
}
```

code `CmdMpuSerialNumber.BuildMessage`

```
public class CmdMpuSerialNumber : CommandBase
{
    // ..

    public TPCANMsg BuildMessage()
    {
        var msg = new TPCANMsg();
        msg.DATA = new byte[] { 0xAA, 0xAA, 0x08, 0x08, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        msg.LEN = 8;
        msg.MSGTYPE = TPCANMessageType.PCAN_MESSAGE_EXTENDED;
        msg.ID = (uint)CanbusAddress.PC;
        return msg;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are welcome. I think the most important thing is to create an interface, so you can test your own code without hardware dependencies.